# Is there an event that tells me when a mail item moves from the Outbox to the Sent Items Folder

Tags: outlook-addin

I have an outlook plugin( VSTO 2013) and what I want is to get an event just before an Email gets "sent". In other words when an email leaves the outbox and moves to the Sent Folder , I want to be notified.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such event. Application.ItemSend / MailItem.Send events fire just before the message is submitted to the transport provider (you can still cancel the submission).

The next event fires when the message is moved to the Sent Items folder: Items.ItemAdd event fires on the Sent Items folder.